# Localhost Page Cannot be Found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localhost, iis-express-10

I am running Visual Studio 2019 which uses IIS Express for Web applications. It was running fine up till suddenly a website I was working on (ASP.NET Core) crashed and gave an error. I went and fixed the error and now all I get is **https://localhost:44314 can not be reached** (see image 1 below). I have all the routing in the code and even reverted my code to the last working version with still no luck. I have even reinstalled Visual Studio and iisexperess. You can see my startup code below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace Website
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {              
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Check the debug section of your web project and make sure the port was not changed.  Also check the launchSettings.json.... finally stop using IIS Express and just use kestrel for debugging.  I only use IIS Express if I need something very specific to IIS...

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro I still don't know why IIS Express won't work as all the things you had me try worked BUT kestrel works! I will for sure use that for now on. Thank you!

Comment: Clean your solution and then try.@JDM

Comment: Do you update your OS recently? Can you share more details about the OS version you're running on?

Comment: @ScareCrow I tried cleaning and it didn't work

Comment: @FeiHan My OS is Windows 10 Version 1909 build 18363.1139

Comment: You can try to check if any useful logs under `%SystemRoot%\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR` folder. Besides, try to change 44314 to another port and check if it can work.